# Getting posts to exclude from array

Tags: php, wp-query, theme-development, array

I have an array, where keys are the post ID's and values are post titles.

```
$options = [];
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'fields'           => '',
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
$options[ $post->ID ] = $post->post_title;
wp_reset_postdata(); endforeach;
return $options;
```

This array works fine and i can use it in my backend to select posts i wann't to exclude from specific query, but it does not work on frontend, since it excludes only the first post from array.

In query it looks like this:

```
$posts_to_exclude = ! empty( $settings['posts_to_exclude'] ) ? $settings['posts_to_exclude'] : ' (choose post) '; 

$exclude_posts = implode(", ", $posts_to_exclude);
print $exclude_posts;
```

And then in WP Query array:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => $settings['posts_count'],
   'cat' => $posts_category,
   'post__not_in' => array($exclude_posts),
);'
```

I have no idea what i could do wrong. Anyone can save me?

Answer (score 1):

simply not "imploding" your array since `implode()` returns a string and `post__not_in` accepts an array

Comment: I found that array prints like this: 

`Array ( [0] => Post Title 1. [1] => Post Title 2 )`

It gives me numbers counting from 0 instead of ID, only the value (post_title) is fine. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: if that's the content of `$post_to_exclude` you cannot use it in `post__not_in` where the array must be an array of IDs

Comment: That's your array of posts to exclude?  You really need IDs, not titles.

Comment: I need an array of post ID as keys and post titles as Values, for example: 
`10 => Post Title`
It need's to be used for Elementor page builder where i select posts to exclude from query in my custom widget. Then i need to take all of these ID's only and exclude these posts from WP Query

Comment: the problem is that `$settings['posts_to_exclude'] ` is not usable for your needs, I don't know where it comes from so I cannot help you. You can do `$IDs=array(); foreach( $exclude_posts as $exclude){array_push($IDs, get_page_by_title($exclude )->ID ); }` and then use `'post__not_in' =>$IDs` but it's a kind of extra query that can be avoided if the original array would be better formed to fit your needs